# How do I use regex to match a specific word that contains at least one uppercase letter but not all in lowercase?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match one specific word "StackOverflow", "STACKOVERFLOW", or "stACKoverFlow" etc. At least one character should be capitalized, but the word with all lower-case "stackoverflow" should not be matched.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to match the specific word "Stackoverflow" with capitalized letters, not a generic word though.

Comment: Looks like you need to use [`^(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])[sS][tT][Aa][Cc][kK][Oo][Vv][eE][Rr][Ff][Ll][Oo][Ww]$`](http://ideone.com/QZP6Kg). Or instead of `^`/`$`, use `\b` (if it is part of a longer string).

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Straight python is better for this..

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. The problem is solved. I am a new user and I am sorry that I would not be able to up vote for you all.

Comment: @anubhava, that regexp will only recognize words with exactly one uppercase alphabetic.  `^[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$`  should be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using `(?i)` in the middle of the regex won't work in Python as `(?i)` will impact the entire regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

You will have to use this longish regex:

```
regex = re.compile(r"^(?!stackoverflow$)[sS][tT][aA][cC][kK][oO][vV][eE][rR][fF][lL][oO][wW]$");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV0hE8/1)

Answer (score 0):

This uses word boundaries to ensure one word and checks for at least one capital letter

```
import re
text = 'StackOverflow STACKOVERFLOW stACKoverFlow stackoverflow'
matches = re.findall(r'\b.*?[A-Z]{1}.*?\b', text)
#['StackOverflow', ' STACKOVERFLOW', ' stACKoverFlow']
```

This is how to do this without regex. It will match exclusively "stackoverflow" as long as it has at least on capital letter

```
text = 'StackOverflow STACKOVERFLOW stACKoverFlow stackoverflow'
matches = [word for word in text.split() if any(letter.isupper() for letter in word) and word.lower() == 'stackoverflow']
#['StackOverflow', 'STACKOVERFLOW', 'stACKoverFlow']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to match the specific word "Stackoverflow", not a generic word though.

Comment: You stated specifically that "stackoverflow" should not be matched

Comment: Sorry, I should type the word I want to match is "StackOverflow", "Stackoverflow",...., not "stackoverflow". But I want to match that specific word, not a generic word. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I do not want to match any other words like "Hello" though

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\b(?=.*[A-Z])(?i)stackoverflow\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM4tZ7/1)

In python would be like:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b(?=.*[A-Z])(?i)stackoverflow\b')
test_str = u"StackOverflow\nSTACKOVERFLOW\nstACKoverFlow\nstackoverflow\n"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is what I want.

Comment: Check the code in the updated answer to see if it works.

Comment: According to @anubhava ``(?i)`` does not work in python. So I guess his answer is the correct one.